# DateTime saved different from what i chose on input

Tags: jquery, laravel, fullcalendar

I try to add some event on fullcalendar , filed: title, start, and end. Title is saved correctly but start date and end date is saved wrong on my db. Can anyone help me with this problem?

On input form i chose 2022-01-27 - 2022-01-28

On db is saved 1970-01-01 - 1970-01-01 and time is 00:00

```js
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable:true,
        header:{
            left:'prev,next today',
            center:'title',
            right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        events:'/event-calender',
        selectable:true,
        selectHelper: true,
        //When u select some space in the calendar do the following:
        select: function (start, end, allDay) {
            //do something when space selected
            //Show 'add event' modal
            $('#eventModal').modal('show');
        },

  $('#eventSubmit').on('click', function(e){
        // We don't want this to act as a link so cancel the link action
        e.preventDefault();

        doSubmit();
    });
    $('#eventClose').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#eventModal').modal('hide');
    });

    function doSubmit(){
        
        $("#eventModal").modal('hide');
        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent',
           $.ajax ({
                url:"/event-calender/action",
                type:"POST",
                data:{
                    title: $('#title').val(),
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                    type: 'add',
                }
            }),
            true);
       }
```

This is controller

```js
public function action(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            if($request->type == 'add')
            {
                $event = Events::create([
                    'title'     =>  $request->title,
                    'start'     =>  $request->start,
                    'end'       =>  $request->end
                ]);
                // dd($event);
                return response()->json($event);
            }
        }
    }
```

Event modal

```js
class Events extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'events';

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'start',
        'end'
    ];
}
```

I changed doSubmit() , and now i get another error like this
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isValid')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER

```js
//When u select some space in the calendar do the following:
        select: function (start, end, allDay) {
            //do something when space selected
            //Show 'add event' modal
            $('#eventModal').modal('show');
            var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

            $('#eventSubmit').on('click', function(e){
                // We don't want this to act as a link so cancel the link action
                e.preventDefault();

                doSubmit();
            });

            $('#eventClose').on('click', function(e) {
                $('#eventModal').modal('hide');
            });

            function doSubmit(){
                
                $("#eventModal").modal('hide');
                $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                $.ajax ({
                        url:"/event-calender/action",
                        type:"POST",
                        data:{
                            title: $('#title').val(),
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            type: 'add',
                        },
                        success:function(data)
                        {
                            calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            // Swal.fire("Event Created Successfully");
                        }
                    }),
                true);
            }
        },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: `ANSWER`...yes we know, because you posted it in the answers section.  What you need to tell us is what you changed in the code in order to solve  the  problem,  and why. Code dumps don't make useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Carbon.](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

```
use Carbon\Carbon;


...

$event = Events::create([
    'title' => $request->title,
    'start  => Carbon::parse($request->start),
    'end' => Carbon::parse($request->end),
]);
```

When `start` and / or `end` are allowed to be null, you can use `Carbon::make()` instead of `Carbon::parse()`.

Another option is to use `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->start);`

Also, make sure `start` and `end` are added to the `$fillable` property on the `Events` model.

Comment: Now i get this error on network tab `message: "Could not parse 'Invalid Date': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (Invalid Date) at position 0 (I): The timezone could not be found in the database"`

Comment: even with `Carbon::make()` same error. Also i have added this filed on `$fillable`  on `Event` model. Just updated my question

Comment: Could you try `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->start);`?

Comment: Now i get this `message: "A four digit year could not be found\nData missing"`   NOTE: I have start and end not null on db

Comment: Make sure the format of `$request->start` is indeed `Y-m-d`, i.e. (2022-01-27).

Comment: Yes the format is `Y-m-d` on db is saved like this `1970-01-01 00:00:00`

Comment: Maybe this way i updated now my question is more easy way. To get date by selection on fullcalendar?

Comment: What is the value of `$request->start`?

Comment: I have fixed. Posting answer